# Install old version of Homebrew on Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, homebrew

So I have a computer that is stuck on Snow Leopard.

How do I install Homebrew on such a old computer? Is this even possible?

I tried the following command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

However this gives me an error about needing git and I don't know how to install an old version of that.

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried to install brew on Snow Leopard? If so, what have you tried? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Monomeeth yes is throws an error saying I need git.  I do not know how to install an old version of git.

Comment: Thanks for that, but can I ask you add to the question the actual Terminal command you tried using? This helps ensure that I (or others) don't suggest what you've already tried. :)

Comment: @Monomeeth included the command I'm not sitting at the computer currently but it says I need git

Comment: I've added an answer. Very similar to what you tried but without the `/usr/bin/` preceding it. I've just tested it on a Late-2008 MBP running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and it installs fine (remembering to follow it up with the second command).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Don't use Homebrew, use MacPorts!**

MacPorts does lots of work to support old versions of OS X. They [backport kernel symbols](https://github.com/macports/macports-legacy-support) and [standard libraries](https://ports.macports.org/port/libcxx/summary). They maintain bespoke patches and a Snow Leopard build bot. MacPorts might just have the *best* legacy support of *any* Mac project under active development, and it's really kind of incredible.

Running Snow Leopard in 2021, and choosing Homebrew over MacPorts, is *absolute madness!* There is a functionally-equivalent project which actively supports your operating system. Use that one.

Comment: I love using Homebrew, so I avoided this advice, and installed Tigerbrew instead. Unfortunately, even Tigerbrew is missing some important packages. Eventually I ended up using MacPorts because it continues to be maintained.

Comment: Could you copy your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654527/installing-binaries-for-older-macos-versions-with-homebrew? I don't want to do it and take credit for yours.

Comment: Copying and pasting answers across SE sites is generally frowned upon... so I, uh, had perhaps a bit too much fun. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the way for Snow Leopard is to "install as normal" however that gives me this

```
...
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Failed during: /bin/bash -o pipefail -c '/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | /usr/bin/tar xz -m --strip 1'
rogers-macbook:temp rdp$ curl https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Work around:

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install > install`

now download `https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master` in a browser, ex: to this filename `~/Downloads/Homebrew-brew-1.5.8-16-g1ca2ee6.tar.gz`

now edit file named `install`, replace `/usr/bin/curl -#{curl_flags} #{BREW_REPO}/tarball/master` with `cat ~/Downloads/Homebrew-brew-1.5.8-16-g1ca2ee6.tar.gz`

next download https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tarball/master in a browser, ex: to `~/Downloads/Homebrew-homebrew-core-bd37905.tar.gz`

now edit install file, replace `/usr/bin/curl -#{curl_flags} #{CORE_TAP_REPO}/tarball/master` with `cat ~/Downloads/Homebrew-homebrew-core-bd37905.tar.gz`

now run it `ruby install`

You'll probably still need [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198641/xcode-for-snow-leopard-where-to-get) installed, and use the steps in Brad Bell's answer to use it to install curl.

Another option (untested) might be to install xcode, then build curl locally from source (ex: download https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.59.0.tar.bz2 with a browser, unzip it, build as normal to some temp location), put that location's bin folder first in your PATH, then run the normal homebrew installation instructions.

[Tigerbrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/30882) might be an option as well.

Comment: What issue is this getting around?

Comment: This failure when installing: `curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version`

Comment: FYI, the actual issue here is outdated SSL support. You can fix it by using a proxy (without replacing the system curl).

Comment: @Wowfunhappy instructions welcome, I'm not sure how anyway LOL :)

Comment: @rogerdpack I'm trying not to plug my own stuff too much. :) https://jonathanalland.com/legacy-mac-proxy.html Note that curl ignores the system proxy settings by default, you need to set the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable. Also, I very highly recommend using MacPorts over Homebrew on old systems, because MacPorts actually supports them.

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you're not very familiar with Ruby or `curl`, here's a verbose (and slightly updated version) to the otherwise excellent answer by @rogerdpack:

1. Download https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master in a browser
2. Make sure it's saved in ~/Downloads/ (the name will be `Homebrew-brew-[latest version number etc.].tar.gz`)
3. Download https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tarball/master in a browser
4. Make sure it's saved in ~/Downloads/ (the name will be `Homebrew-homebrew-core-[latest version number].tar`)
5. Save the install file to a file, by running this command in terminal:  `curl -o ~/Downloads/install.txt https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install`
6. Edit ~/Downloads/install.txt and
   A. replace `/usr/bin/curl -#{curl_flags} #{BREW_REPO}/tarball/master` with `cat ~/Downloads/Homebrew-brew-[version number etc.].tar.gz`
   B. replace `/usr/bin/curl -#{curl_flags} #{CORE_TAP_REPO}/tarball/master` with `cat ~/Downloads/Homebrew-homebrew-core-[version number etc.].tar.gz`
7. Install by running this command in terminal: `ruby -S ~/Downloads/install.txt`

In my case, the exact filenames were `Homebrew-brew-1.5.14-3-g94c0d83.tar.gz` and `Homebrew-homebrew-core-b83864a.tar`

Answer (score 1):

The current way to install Homebrew in Snow Leopard is to use the following command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

After running this ensure you follow it up with:

```
brew update --force
```

Let me know how you go.

Comment: I tried this and my git version isn't new enough (which is also why my current installation of homebrew on Lion is broken).

Comment: `curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version` but see some of the other answers...

Answer (score 0):

After installing Homebrew using the above steps, you still may not be able to install anything with it, because it wants to download packages using the same outdated version of curl. So you'll need to follow up by installing the homebrew version of curl.

1. Do `brew install curl`
2. Note the file that fails to download, i.e. `https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.59.0.tar.bz2`
3. Download the file using a browser and place it in `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew`
4. repeat `brew install curl`
5. If there are any dependencies that still fail to download, go back to step 2
6. Because the new curl is keg-only, make it your default by running `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"` as well as placing that in your `~/.bash_profile` with `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
7. If you have more failed downloads with `curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations...` download `cacert.pem` from `https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html` and copy it to `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`

You should now have a fully working Homebrew!

Comment: How do I run `brew install curl` with out hombrew installed?

Comment: @William  First you follow the instructions by user1092247 or rogerdpack. The steps by user1092247 worked for me. It installs homebrew, but most `brew install ...` commands still fail

Comment: did you need xcode installed first?

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of curl using macport, then install brew (or tigerbrew) using the normal method.

1. Install macport using an installer that can be downloaded here, choose the one for your version of OS X. Support goes back to 10.4 Tiger.
   https://github.com/macports/macports-base/releases/tag/v2.6.4
2. After installing is done. Open a new terminal, and type
   port install curl
3. you may also need to install git,
   port install git
4. Follow the instruction at https://brew.sh/ to install homebrew
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   4a. if brew refuse to install because your machine is too old as my early 2006 iMac 20in running on the 32-bit Core Duo. Try tigerbrew
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew/go/install)",
   which works on my old iMac perfectly.

Comment: If you install macports then just use that for all. You don't need homebrew. Also macports and homebre don't interact well especially on older versions of OSX

Comment: agree. macport is actually a much better choice than homebrew for old mac