# Installing Homebrew on Snow Leopard (10.6.8)? (-Curl is outdated.)

Tags: macos, homebrew, snow-leopard, error, ruby

I'm using a machine that needs to remain at OS X 10.6.8 for the time being.

Trying to install Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

But I get the following error:

```
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Based on other posts, I'm pretty sure this is because the version of Curl I have is too old/outdated (7.19.7).

- How can I update Curl to get it working?
- Alternatively, how can I get Homebrew installed without using Curl?

*-Thanks for any help/info.!*

Comment: Having used homebrew on macOS 10.15 due to an add-in card requirement, my only advice would be to not attempt to use homebrew on a machine of this vintage. If you need to install something, your best bet will be to do so manually. It sucks, but homebrew is just going to cause more pain.

Comment: Homebrew does not support Snow Leopard.  They support the current release of macOS and two releases back.  So the presently supported are Monterey, Ventura, and Sonoma.

Answer (score 1):

Toss homebrew, and get [macports](https://www.macports.org/index.php). Snow Leopard is still supported, and you can get an up-to-date version of `curl` that should cure your problems. There's a page dedicated to [installing macports](https://www.macports.org/install.php#installing), which includes this passage:

> Using the latest available version that will run on your OS is highly recommended, except for Snow Leopard where the last free version, 3.2.6, is recommended

I've never used it (macports) on Snow Leopard, but I've used it for years on systems of late 2011 vintage. It's solid.

EDIT:  Here's an [answer from 2021](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418277/149366) that includes additional details.